# Why do we use the dispose() method in Flutter Dart code?

Tags: flutter, dart

Why are we using `dispose()` method? I'm little confused about it.
what will be issue occurs If we don't use it and what's the benefit of using it?

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: 'dispose()' is called when the State object is removed, which is permanent

Comment: The `dispose` method does not apply directly to the Dart language. It only applies to the Flutter platform.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**dispose** method used to release the memory allocated to variables when state object is removed.

For example, if you are using a stream in your application then you have to release memory allocated to the stream controller. Otherwise, your app may get a warning from the PlayStore and AppStore about memory leakage.

Comment: Sir, would you please explain me about memory leakage?

Comment: memory leak is a type of resource leak that occurs when a computer program incorrectly manages memory allocations in such a way that memory which is no longer needed is not released.

Comment: So sir, which issue will be produced if memory leakage happens?any example?

Comment: Memory leakage don't create any issue but it is sign of bad application.

Comment: Memory leaks can lead to out of memory errors, and in the best case scenario 1) your application will be terminated  by the operating system unexpectedly and with bad user experience. In the worst case scenario, 2) it can also lead to the entire system performing poorly, because your application is slowly "eating" all the memory available, and the operating system has to deal with such a large amount of virtual memory that has to constantly page to make your program happy while keeping everything running. Long story short -> your entire system becomes sloppy and unresponsive.

Comment: Imho this answer is confusing. Dart is a garbage collected language, which typically implies that it isn't necessary to manually release memory. In contrast to manual memory management, you do not have to e.g. release the memory of string in `dispose`. I'd assume that a non-trivial `dispose` is only necessary if something prevents reference counts from reaching zero, which is the true reason of the perceived memory leak. It still isn't clear to me exactly under which circumstances this can happen.

Comment: @bluenote10 garbage collection doesn't happen magically. There are many situations where the garbage collector will not dispose of resources because they are connected to existing things like open streams. You have to close those before the garbage collector can do anything.

Comment: Is there linter available to warns when an instance that has a dispose method is not assigned to a variable?

Answer (score 17):

`dispose()` method called automatically from stateful if not defined.

In some cases dispose is required for example in `CameraPreview`, `Timer` etc.. you have to close the stream.

When closing the stream is required you have to use it in dispose method.

`dispose()` is used to execute code when the screen is disposed. Equal to `onDestroy()` of Android.

Example:

```
@override
void dispose() {
  cameraController?.dispose();
  timer.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Okay now I'm getting little bit means dispose() ==onDestroy(). and if I don't use it?

Comment: If you are not using anything special which requires compulsory closing the stream as i given example like Timer, CameraPreview etc. Then it is not required to compulsory override and use it.

Comment: This is what i need. The implementation! Thanks!

Comment: What else the implementation of `dispose`? @ParthPatel

Comment: What are the cases that require manual disposal? You mentioned two cases only. Would like to know this. @ParthPatel

Answer (score 11):

*The main purpose is to get a callback where in you can free-up all your resources.*

If you have initialized any resource in a State, it is important that you close or destroy that resource when that state is disposed.

For e.g: If you are creating a stream in initState of your `StatefullWidget`, then it is important that you close that stream in `dispose` method of that state or else it will cause memory leak.

For more details you can refer following comments which I got from the source code of the `dispose` method of the `StatefulWidget`:

> Called when this object is removed from the tree permanently. The
>   framework calls this method when this [State] object will never build
>   again. After the framework calls [dispose], the [State] object is
>   considered unmounted and the [mounted] property is false. It is an
>   error to call [setState] at this point. This stage of the lifecycle is
>   terminal: there is no way to remount a [State] object that has been
>   disposed. Subclasses should override this method to release any
>   resources retained by this object (e.g., stop any active animations).
>   {@macro flutter.widgets.subscriptions} If you override this, make sure
>   to end your method with a call to super.dispose(). See also: *
>   [deactivate], which is called prior to [dispose].

Or you can refer the docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html

So basically dispose is called when that current state will never be used again. So, if you are having any listeners that are active in that state then they can cause memory leaks and so you should close them.

Answer (score 6):

Well, the answer is in the word dispose of. so imagine you are at a party and there is a table where glasses of water are placed which are plastic glasses. Now you will get one glass use it and dispose (throw it into the dustbin). if you don't do that you place the same glass on the table then there will be no place for other new glasses to be put(memory error). Because the table is full now. The second thing is if you put a glass on the table it's possible there might some drink is left. so if someone else uses that glass then there will be something in it already. (controller already having some value if you don't dispose and the same form or animation controller on the same screen).

happy scene:- all take glasses of drink and dispose them into dustbin so all table will also get space and everybody will get new drink not the old drink of someone.

Practical where I got to know the accurate use- I made a screen where inline editing was needed means you click the button all text converts into text form fields and you change the required values and press that button again to submit(icon change of the same button on editing),

So the word dispose expose everything about its use I hope this real-life example will help a little bit. Thank you

```
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _editButtonAnimationController.dispose();
    _ageController.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

dispose() method is called when this object is removed from the tree permanently.

For more information, you can refer official Docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html

Implementation Example:

```
@protected
@mustCallSuper
void dispose() {
  assert(_debugLifecycleState == _StateLifecycle.ready);
  assert(() {
    _debugLifecycleState = _StateLifecycle.defunct;
    return true;
  }());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In general terms `dispose` means freeing the resources before the related object is removed from the focus. By focus, I mean from `widget tree` or `navigation stack` whichever is relevant.

When you call dispose on a [`widget state`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html), the associated widget is supposed to be `unmounted` which means the widget will never rebuild.

> Called when this object is removed from the tree permanently.
>
> The framework calls this method when this State object will never build again.
>
> After the framework calls dispose, the State object is considered unmounted and the mounted 
>   property is false. It is an error to call setState at this point.
>
> This stage of the lifecycle is terminal: there is no way to remount a State object that has been 
>   disposed.

When you call dispose on a `bloc`, the bloc is supposed to be closing the `event` and `state` stream.
**Update:** New Bloc does not have `dispose`, instead it has `close`.

So, This is what `dispose` basically means.

**TL;DR**
In general, it means releasing the resources held by the associated instance/object.

The specific meaning of `dispose`, however, changes with the types of the object on which this method is called.

Answer (score 2):

Given all the answers above regarding garbage collection and examples of what to put in dispose(), it seems like the general idea is to dispose/cancel anything that has a future or is tied to hardware access, because you don't want to return to a non-existent object or to block other apps from using that resource (ex.camera, file system, microphone, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

The `dispose()` method is called in the `State` object of a widget when the widget is removed from the tree permanently, typically when the user navigates to a different screen or closes the app.

Its basically used to clean up any resources used by the widget, such as animations, streams, or timers.

```dart
@override
void dispose() {    //:/  only gets called when the State is Destroyed
  // TODO: implement dispose
  super.dispose();
  print("DISPOSE function caled...");
}
```

When `dispose()` is called, the `State` object is removed from the widget tree, and its `build()` method will not be called again.

Therefore, it is important to dispose of any resources that were created in `initState()` method, such as controllers, animation objects, or subscriptions to streams, to prevent memory leaks or unexpected behavior.

**Can read more here:**
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html

Answer (score 1):

You should not only override `dispose` method to free up some memory  but also to dispose those objects that would otherwise be visible on the screen like a `BannerAd`.

Say, you have a `BannerAd` and you don't dispose the instance of `bannerAd` and navigate back to the previous page, your ad would still be visible on the screen which you don't want. So, you must dispose it like:

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
  bannerAd?.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We uses `dispose()` method in order to stop/avoid memory linkage when state object is removed from the widget tree.