# AnimatedBuilder with two different types of animations not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to animate the color and the value of a `CircularProgressIndicator` I want it to go from 0-1 and from pink to orange in 15 seconds. Here's everything I tried:

```
TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
                tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1),
                curve: Curves.easeOut,
                duration: Duration(seconds: 15),
                builder: (context, value, _) {
                  Color strokeColor = Colors.pink;
                  if (value > 0.5) strokeColor = Colors.orange;

                  return CircularProgressIndicator(
                      strokeWidth: 8, value: value, valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(strokeColor));
                }),
```

That animated the value, but not the valueColor/stroke color. I have to somehow pass `ColorTween(begin: Colors.pink, end: Colors.orange)` to the valueColor, but I'm not sure how... I replacing the TweenAnimationBuilder with a AnimatedBuilder, but I ran into issues since the animation can only use 1 type of value, i.e. either a double or a color, but can't do both...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use a [AnimatedBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedBuilder-class.html) to pass a [ColorTween](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/ColorTween-class.html) and a [Tween](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Tween-class.html) to control the color and the value of the [CircularProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html), respectively.

In order to do so:

1. We need to use the [SingleTickerProviderStateMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleTickerProviderStateMixin-mixin.html) on our parent [StatefulWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html):

```
class _MyProgressIndicator extends State<MyProgressIndicator>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

// ...

}
```

2. Initialize the [AnimationController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html), `ColorTween`, `Tween<double>`, and starting the `AnimationController` by overriding the `initState()` method:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 15),
      vsync: this,
    );
    _animationColor = ColorTween(
      begin: Colors.pink,
      end: Colors.orange,
    ).animate(_controller);
    _animationValue = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(_controller);
    _controller.forward();
  }
```

3. Don't forget the `AnimationController` by overriding the `dispose()` method!

```
@override        
  void dispose() {            
   _controller.dispose();            
   super.dispose();            
  }
```

A full example is displayed below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyProgressIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  MyProgressIndicator({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyProgressIndicator createState() => _MyProgressIndicator();
}

class _MyProgressIndicator extends State<MyProgressIndicator>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<Color> _animationColor;
  Animation<double> _animationValue;
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 15),
      vsync: this,
    );
    _animationColor = ColorTween(
      begin: Colors.pink,
      end: Colors.orange,
    ).animate(_controller);
    _animationValue = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1).animate(_controller);
    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _controller,
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator(
              strokeWidth: 8,
              value: _animationValue.value,
              valueColor: _animationColor,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override        
  void dispose() {            
   _controller.dispose();            
   super.dispose();            
  }
}
```

Comment: When am I supoosed to dispose elements?

Comment: It's important to dispose the classes that can cause memory leakage, here you can read a bit more about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59558604/why-do-we-use-dispose-method-in-dart-code