# When gets a flutter widget disposed?

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter widget which holds state on a page. After it goes out of vision it gets disposed and with it its state. After scrolling up again it gets recreated with its initial state, which is unintended.

I cant find any information how Flutter decides if it is disposing a widget. So, when does a flutter widget get disposed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the widget is no longer running, it calls dispose method. Simple way when that state is no longer used on UI. This is depending on where you are using those statefullWidgets.

Like on `Listview.builder` it renders only visible widgets+ some portion of top and bottom. Here, rest of the widgets will be disposed if it created. You can also check with `Listview`.

Another case is when we wrap everything with `SingleChildScrollView` it will dispose all widget at end. For more visit those link and test this widget(you can try dev-tools).

> `dispose` Called when this object is removed from the tree permanently.

> The framework calls this method when this State object will never build again. After the framework calls dispose, the State object is considered unmounted and the mounted property is false. It is an error to call setState at this point. This stage of the lifecycle is terminal: there is no way to remount a State object that has been disposed...

For more visit

- [dispose method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html)
- [why do we use dispose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59558604/10157127)

**Test widget**

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  final items = List.generate(
    23,
    (index) => Sub1(
      subNo: index,
      key: UniqueKey(),
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: items,
        ),
      ),
      //  ListView.builder(
      //     itemCount: 20, itemBuilder: (context, index) => items[index]),
    );
  }
}

class Sub1 extends StatefulWidget {
  final int subNo;

  const Sub1({
    Key? key,
    required this.subNo,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Sub1State createState() => _Sub1State();
}

class _Sub1State extends State<Sub1> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("init Sub ${widget.subNo}");
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("dispose Sub  ${widget.subNo}");
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      color: widget.subNo.isEven ? Colors.deepPurple : Colors.deepOrange,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text("Sub ${widget.subNo}"),
    );
  }
}
```