# Flutter - What is the difference between dispose() and removeListener()?

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't completely understand the difference between the both methods and when to use them, anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

[`dispose`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html): The framework calls this method when this State object will never build again. After the framework calls dispose, the State object is considered unmounted, and the mounted property is false. It is an error to call setState at this point. This stage of the lifecycle is terminal: there is no way to remount a State object that has been disposed.

You can find more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59558604/10157127).

[`removeListener`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier/removeListener.html): Remove a previously registered closure from the list of closures that are notified when the object changes.

**[`removeListener`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier/removeListener.html) must not be called after  [`dispose`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html) has been called.**

[`listener`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Listener-class.html) is a widget that calls callbacks in response to common pointer events.

More and ref :  [`dispose`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html), [`removeListener`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier/removeListener.html), [`listener`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Listener-class.html) and  [SO Question on dispose](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59558604/10157127).