# Flutter // Understanding dispose

Tags: flutter, dispose, lifecycle

The more things I do, the more often I run across things that need disposing (e. g. Timers and ScrollControllers). Two questions:

1. Is there a way to see/know what things need to be disposed? Or is it just a thing you need to learn by heart? For example: At the moment I'm not sure, if I need to dispose of providers.
2. Do I need to expose things (e. g. Timers) in stateless widgets? If so how? Or do I turn a widget stateful just so I gain access to the dispose method? That seems wasteful.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we use dispose() method in dart code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59558604/why-do-we-use-dispose-method-in-dart-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If disposing is needed, it's usually stated in docs.
2. It's not about turning into a stateful widget "just to gain access to the dispose method". It's turning into a stateful widget because *it has a state*. If it contains a timer, it already implies having a state. Think of stateless widgets as pure functions – you can call them several times and there should be no side effects. Timer is such a side effect since you don't want it to be re-created on every stateless widget creating. Also, there's no significant performance impact on converting stateless widget to stateful.