# Flutter :- Why we need to close stream data or any controller?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, stream

- Why closing stream when it don not use is best practise
- How much effect on app's performance

Any other information also accepted Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I think this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59558604/why-do-we-use-the-dispose-method-in-flutter-dart-code).

If you dont, those Memory resources get permanently blocked.