# What needs to use Dispose in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, memory-leaks, state

UPDATE: I have a general idea of what dispose does.  But I want a list of specific items have to be disposed, like: text controllers, stream controllers, or "any and all variables declared in a Stateful page"...

Here is the original post:
...
I know you use Dispose to "clean up" a Stateful page.  And I have used it for textfield controllers.  But I am unclear on:

1. what types of things need to be disposed? (besides textfield controllers)
2. what happens if you don't dispose? (memory leaks?)

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we use the dispose() method in Flutter Dart code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59558604/why-do-we-use-the-dispose-method-in-flutter-dart-code)

Comment: When you have an ongoing stream, or a timer, or you want to run some code when you quit that screen. For example in my app one screen is in landscape mode, the rest are in portrait mode. So in the widget where the phone should be in landscape mode, I set the default mode to `landscape` in the `initState()` and I set back to `portrait` in `dispose` after the user leaves that screen.

Comment: @mohammadesmaili Thanks, but I really want the specific examples of what needs to be disposed.  (But your link does explain the 2nd part of my question about memory leaks.)

Answer (score 1):

`dispose` method is used to release the memory allocated to variables when the state object is removed.

For example, if you are using a `stream` in your application then you have to release memory allocated to the `stream controller`. Otherwise, your app may get a warning from the PlayStore and AppStore about memory leakage.

Comment: So does *every* declared variable have to be disposed, or only certain ones? If it is only certain ones, is there a list?