# Why we need to call `dispose` method while member is property of the disposed class?

Tags: flutter, dart, dispose

I am looking at the flutter example below;

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes#interactive-example

it has code like;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Retrieve Text Input',
      home: MyCustomForm(),
    );
  }
}

// Define a custom Form widget.
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomForm({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyCustomForm> createState() => _MyCustomFormState();
}

// Define a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the Form.
class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  // Create a text controller and use it to retrieve the current value
  // of the TextField.
  final myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Start listening to changes.
    myController.addListener(_printLatestValue);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is removed from the widget tree.
    // This also removes the _printLatestValue listener.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _printLatestValue() {
    print('Second text field: ${myController.text}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Retrieve Text Input'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              onChanged: (text) {
                print('First text field: $text');
              },
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: myController,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and following method within;

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is removed from the widget tree.
    // This also removes the _printLatestValue listener.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

What I see here `myController` is already instance of `_MyCustomFormState` class. So my assumption is once `MyCustomForm` widget removed from widget tree, all it's instance members should be automatically disposed right? But it is recommended to call `dispose` method of those members explicitly.

Can I learn why framework does not do it itself and we need to handle it? I would understand if that holds a handle to a file system which is outside of that class scope, but what I see in there there is no handle of this controller outside of the scope.

Comment: Check here out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59558604/why-do-we-use-the-dispose-method-in-flutter-dart-code

Comment: It gives idea of why disposing concept is there. I don't see a specific answer to my question. @Benyamin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an instance is no longer used, (like your `_MyCustomFormState`), it is automatically garbage-collected, together with all the references it contains, like your `myController`.

However, a `TextEditingController` instance may have more resources attached to it than can be reclaimed by simple garbage collection.
Therefore is is recommended to call its `dispose` method before the memory is reclaimed.

Unlike for instance C++, Dart does not have a concept of destructors for its classes, so the call to `dispose` methods is needed.